# C# WPF call method from user control in window

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls, listbox

i have a huge problem....
i have a MainWindow.xaml. this xaml is seperated into differnt columns and rows. in. on the left side i have my different buttons. on the right side i have my so called content grid. in this content grid i open my different user controls by pressing a button.

in one of these user controls i request a route from A to B. if the points are excatly identified the route gets displays in the listbox below the input screen.

but if one of the two points isn't exactly identified i open a new window with two comboboxes where you have to specify and select your inputs. after choosing your start and destination points. the window should be closed by pressing the button OK and in the listbox in the user control the route should bey displayed....but it doesn't...

my english isn't that good and i hope you can help me by posting the code..

The Code behind file of the User Control:

```
RoutenplanungSelection rps = new RoutenplanungSelection();
public void checkStationsnamenSindEindeutig(string von, string nach, string datum, string zeit, bool abfahrt)
    {

        WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        wc.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        string data = wc.DownloadString(....url);
        var xe = XElement.Parse(data);

        var CountOrigins = from a in xe.Descendants("itdOdv")
                           where a.Attribute("usage").Value == "origin"
                           select a.Element("itdOdvName").Elements("odvNameElem").Count();

        var CountDestinations = from a in xe.Descendants("itdOdv")
                                where a.Attribute("usage").Value == "destination"
                                select a.Element("itdOdvName").Elements("odvNameElem").Count();



        int countorigins = 0;
        foreach (var c in CountOrigins)
            countorigins = Convert.ToInt32(c);

        int countdestinations = 0;
        foreach (var c in CountDestinations)
            countdestinations = Convert.ToInt32(c);

        if (countorigins == 1 && countdestinations == 1)
        {
            downloadEindeutigenXml(von, nach, datum, zeit, abfahrt);
        }



        if (countorigins > 1 || countdestinations > 1)
        {
            var getAllOrigins = from a in xe.Descendants("itdOdv")
                                where a.Attribute("usage").Value == "origin"
                                select a;

            var getAllDestinations = from a in xe.Descendants("itdOdv")
                                where a.Attribute("usage").Value == "destination"
                                select a;


            foreach(var r in getAllOrigins)
                rps.uebergebeXmlOrigins(r);

            foreach (var r in getAllDestinations)
                rps.uebergebeXmlDestination(r);

            rps.uebergebeAllgemeineInfos(datum, zeit, abfahrt);
            rps.Show();


        }

    }



    public async void downloadEindeutigenXml(string von, string nach, string datum, string zeit, bool abfahrt)
    {


        WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        wc.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        if(abfahrt) 
        {
            this.mw = (MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow;
            mw.progress.IsIndeterminate = false;
            mw.progress.IsIndeterminate = true;
            formatEindeutigeData(XElement.Parse(await wc.DownloadStringTaskAsync(
            "....url")));
            mw.progress.IsIndeterminate = false;
        }
        else 
        {
            this.mw = (MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow;
            mw.progress.IsIndeterminate = false;
            mw.progress.IsIndeterminate = true;
            formatEindeutigeData(XElement.Parse(await wc.DownloadStringTaskAsync(
            "....url")));
            mw.progress.IsIndeterminate = false;
        }
    }

    private string addZeros(string number)
    {
        if (number.Length < 2)
            return number.Insert(0, "0");
        else
            return number;

    }
    private void formatEindeutigeData(XElement xml)
    {

        box.Items.Clear();
        var checkConnections = (from a in xml.Descendants("itdMessage")
                               where a.Attribute("code").Value == "-4000"
                               select a).Count();



        var checkDateValid = (from a in xml.Descendants("itdMessage")
                              where a.Attribute("code").Value == "-4001"
                              select a).Count();

        if (checkConnections == 1)
        {
            TextBlock nothing = new TextBlock();
            nothing.TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center;
            nothing.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
            nothing.FontSize = 18;
            nothing.Text = "\n\n\nLeider gibt es keine Verbindung zu Ihrem gewünschten Ziel! :-(";
            box.Items.Add(nothing);
        }

        if (checkDateValid == 1)
        {
            TextBlock nothing = new TextBlock();
            nothing.TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center;
            nothing.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
            nothing.FontSize = 18;
            nothing.Text = "\n\n\nDatum außerhalb der Fahrplanperiode! :-(";
            box.Items.Add(nothing);
        } 




        var result = (from a in xml.Descendants("itdRouteList").Elements("itdRoute")
                     select new
                     {
                         partialRoute = from b in a.Descendants("itdPartialRouteList").Elements("itdPartialRoute")
                                        select new 
                                        {
                                            von = from c in b.Elements("itdPoint")
                                                  where c.Attribute("usage").Value == "departure"
                                                  select new 
                                                  {
                                                      station = c.Attribute("name").Value,
                                                      abfahrtdatum_jahr = c.Element("itdDateTimeTarget").Element("itdDate").Attribute("year").Value,
                                                      abfahrtdatum_monat = c.Element("itdDateTimeTarget").Element("itdDate").Attribute("month").Value,
                                                      abfahrtdatum_tag = c.Element("itdDateTimeTarget").Element("itdDate").Attribute("day").Value,
                                                      abfahrtdatum_stunde = addZeros(c.Element("itdDateTimeTarget").Element("itdTime").Attribute("hour").Value),
                                                      abfahrtdatum_minute = addZeros(c.Element("itdDateTimeTarget").Element("itdTime").Attribute("minute").Value)
                                                  },
                                            nach = from c in b.Elements("itdPoint")
                                                   where c.Attribute("usage").Value == "arrival"
                                                   select new
                                                   {
                                                       station = c.Attribute("name").Value,
                                                       ankuftdatum_jahr = c.Element("itdDateTimeTarget").Element("itdDate").Attribute("year").Value,
                                                       ankuftdatum_monat = c.Element("itdDateTimeTarget").Element("itdDate").Attribute("month").Value,
                                                       ankuftdatum_tag = c.Element("itdDateTimeTarget").Element("itdDate").Attribute("day").Value,
                                                       ankuftdatum_stunde = addZeros(c.Element("itdDateTimeTarget").Element("itdTime").Attribute("hour").Value),
                                                       ankuftdatum_minute = addZeros(c.Element("itdDateTimeTarget").Element("itdTime").Attribute("minute").Value)
                                                   },
                                            fahrmittel = from c in b.Elements("itdMeansOfTransport")
                                                         select new 
                                                         {
                                                             name_plus_linie = c.Attribute("name").Value,
                                                             linie = c.Attribute("shortname").Value,
                                                             symbol = c.Attribute("symbol").Value,
                                                             richtung = c.Attribute("destination").Value
                                                         }

                                        },
                            fahrzeit = a.Element("seqRoutes").Element("seqRoute").Attribute("publicDuration").Value

                     }).ToList();


        foreach (var r in result)
        {

            foreach (var q in r.partialRoute)
            {
                foreach (var s in q.von)
                {
                    foreach (var t in q.nach)
                    {
                        foreach (var a in q.fahrmittel)
                        {
                            //MessageBox.Show("von: " + s.ToString() + " nach: " + t.ToString() + " mittels " + a.name_plus_linie + " richtung " + a.richtung + "fahrzeit: " + r.fahrzeit);

                            TextBlock tb_name_linie_richtung = new TextBlock();
                            tb_name_linie_richtung.FontSize = 18;
                            if (a.name_plus_linie != "" && a.richtung != "")
                                tb_name_linie_richtung.Text = a.name_plus_linie + ", Richtung " + a.richtung;
                            else
                                tb_name_linie_richtung.Text = "Fußweg";
                            box.Items.Add(tb_name_linie_richtung);

                        }
                        TextBlock uhrzeit_von = new TextBlock();
                        uhrzeit_von.Text = s.abfahrtdatum_stunde + ":" + s.abfahrtdatum_minute + "   " + s.station;
                        box.Items.Add(uhrzeit_von);

                        TextBlock uhrzeit_nach = new TextBlock();
                        uhrzeit_nach.Text = t.ankuftdatum_stunde + ":" + t.ankuftdatum_minute + "   " + t.station;
                        box.Items.Add(uhrzeit_nach);

                    }

                }

            }
            box.Items.Add(new TextBlock().Text = "\n\n");


        }

    }
```

XAML of the user control:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WLive.Routenplanung"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Input.Toolkit"
         xmlns:Controls="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/controls"
         xmlns:ControlsExtended="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WLive">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <local:FontSizeConverter x:Key="fontSizeCon" />
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="8*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="92*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="11*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="11*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="8*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="10*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="8*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="52*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Label Content="Von: " Grid.Column="0" FontSize="18" Grid.Row="0" />
    <toolkit:AutoCompleteBox x:Name="tbvon" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" FilterMode="Contains" MinimumPrefixLength="4" 
             FontSize="{Binding Path=ActualHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Grid}, Converter={StaticResource fontSizeCon}}" TextChanged="routevon_TextChanged"/>
    <Label Content="Nach: " Grid.Column="0" FontSize="18" Grid.Row="1"/>
    <toolkit:AutoCompleteBox x:Name="tbnach" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" FilterMode="Contains" MinimumPrefixLength="4" 
             FontSize="{Binding Path=ActualHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Grid}, Converter={StaticResource fontSizeCon}}" TextChanged="routenach_TextChanged"/>
    <RadioButton x:Name="radioabf" Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Content="Abfahrt" FontSize="18" IsChecked="True"/>
    <RadioButton x:Name="radioank" Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Content="Ankunft" FontSize="18" Margin="100 0 0 0"/>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
        <ControlsExtended:DateTimePicker x:Name="datumsscheisse"></ControlsExtended:DateTimePicker>
    </StackPanel>
    <Button x:Name="butabfragen" Grid.Row="4" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" FontSize="18" Content="Route berechnen" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Click="abfragen_Click" />
    <ListBox x:Name="box" Grid.Row="5" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
    </ListBox>

</Grid>
```

the code behind file of the routenplanungSelection

```
        private string datum;

    public string Datum
    {
        get { return datum; }
        set { datum = value; }
    }
    private string zeit;

    public string Zeit
    {
        get { return zeit; }
        set { zeit = value; }
    }
    private bool abfahrt;

    public bool Abfahrt
    {
        get { return abfahrt; }
        set { abfahrt = value; }
    }



    public RoutenplanungSelection()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void uebergebeXmlOrigins(XElement xml)
    {

        var getAllOrigins = from a in xml.Descendants("odvNameElem")
                            select new
                            {
                                id = a.Attribute("id").Value,
                                name = a.Value
                            };

        foreach (var r in getAllOrigins)
        {
            comboabfahrt.ItemsSource = getAllOrigins;
        }
    }


    public void uebergebeXmlDestination(XElement xml)
    {

        var getAllDestinations = from a in xml.Descendants("odvNameElem")
                                 select new
                                 {
                                     id = a.Attribute("id").Value,
                                     name = a.Value
                                 };

        foreach (var r in getAllDestinations)
        {
            comboziel.ItemsSource = getAllDestinations;
        }
    }




    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string abfahrtid = comboabfahrt.SelectedValue.ToString();
        string zielid = comboziel.SelectedValue.ToString();


        new Routenplanung().downloadEindeutigenXml(abfahrtid, zielid, Datum, Zeit, Abfahrt);


    }

    public void uebergebeAllgemeineInfos(string datum, string zeit, bool abfahrt)
    {
        Datum = datum;
        Zeit = zeit;
        Abfahrt = abfahrt;
    }
```

XAML of the window:

```
<Controls:MetroWindow x:Class="WLive.RoutenplanungSelection"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:Controls="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/controls"
    Title="WLive - Routenplanung, Haltestellenspezifikation" Height="230" Width="400" MinHeight="230" MinWidth="400">
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="15*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="85*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Label Content="Bitte spezifizieren Sie Ihre Eingaben:" FontSize="18" Foreground="Red" FontWeight="Bold" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"/>
    <Label Content="Von:" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" FontSize="24" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>
    <Label Content="Nach:" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" FontSize="20" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>
    <ComboBox x:Name="comboabfahrt" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" DisplayMemberPath="name" SelectedValuePath="id" SelectedIndex="0" />
    <ComboBox x:Name="comboziel" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" DisplayMemberPath="name" SelectedValuePath="id" SelectedIndex="0" />
    <Button Grid.Row="3" Margin="0 5 5 5" HorizontalAlignment="Right" FontSize="20" Grid.Column="1" Click="Button_Click">OK</Button>
</Grid>
```

my aim is if the new window appears, i specifiy my station, the i click on OK, the window closes and in the listbox my result gets displays.
everything works, cause if i say MessageBox.Show(xml.ToString()); in the formatData(XElement xml) Method it displays me the right xml file...but it doesn't appear in the listbox....

Comment: You should post your xaml... How did you binded your source to the Listbox? Moreover I give you two little hints: 1) methods should have their own name starting with an upper case letter. 2) do not write "it's an homework", "it's a project for my course" and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look to the `Button_Click` method of your `RoutenplanungSelection` window: first you retrive a couple of selected values, then you ***create a new instance*** of `Routenplanung` window.

Of course that new instance is not the same instance of the main window you see on the screen. In your secondary window you should have a reference to the main one.